# Testing whether a list contains certain mandatory and certain optional items

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, crtp, assertj

I was trying to create a unit test which would make sure a *list* (or, more generally, a *container*) contains certain mandatory items, while allowing it to also contain some extra optional items (but, again, from a pre-defined list of options).

Let's assume, for definiteness, that the list:

1. **must** contain items `foo` and `bar`;
2. **may** contain item `optional`;
3. **may not** contain any other items.

In Java, using a handy `satisfiesAnyOf()` function from the [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core) library, this test can be written as follows:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class C {
    @Test
    public void t0() {
        doTest(asList("foo", "bar"));
    }

    @Test
    public void t1() {
        doTest(asList("foo", "bar", "optional"));
    }

    private static void doTest(final List<String> items) {
        assertThat(items).as("items").satisfiesAnyOf(
                it -> assertThat(it).as("XXX").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar"),
                it -> assertThat(it).as("YYY").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar", "optional"));
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it only compiles using a **Java 8** compiler, with **Java 9+** compilers rejecting it with:

```
C.java:[26,63] no suitable method found for containsExactlyInAnyOrder(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    method org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIterableAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.String...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.String)
    method org.assertj.core.api.ListAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.String...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.String)
C.java:[27,63] no suitable method found for containsExactlyInAnyOrder(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    method org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIterableAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.String...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.String)
    method org.assertj.core.api.ListAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.String...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.String)
```

The client code can easily be fixed by explicitly casting `it` in each lambda from `List<? extends String>` to `List<String>` which doesn't even change the generated bytecode:

```
        assertThat(items).as("items").satisfiesAnyOf(
                it -> assertThat((List<String>) it).as("XXX").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar"),
                it -> assertThat((List<String>) it).as("YYY").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar", "optional"));
```

Looking at *AssertJ* API, I can't figure out how exactly the above issue can be addressed w/o unsafe casts.

Speaking in favour of *Kotlin*, the equivalent *Kotlin* code compiles just fine (the type of `it` can be specified as either `MutableList<out String>` or `List<String>`):

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4

@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class K {
  @Test
  fun t() {
    val items = listOf("foo", "bar", "optional")

    assertThat(items).`as`("items").satisfiesAnyOf({ assertThat(it).`as`("XXX").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar") },
                                                   { assertThat(it).`as`("YYY").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("foo", "bar", "optional") })
  }
}
```

#### Questions:

1. What exactly has changed in the JLS between **Java 8** and **Java 9**? Can you point me to the exact section of the specification which forbids successful compilation?
2. How can the above Java code be rewritten to avoid explicit type casts?

Comment: NB: it's better to do `(List<String> it) -> assertThat(...`, rather than casting.

Comment: @AndyTurner Indeed, but this wouldn't compile. The type of the lambda expected by `satisfiesAnyOf()` should be `Consumer<List<? extends String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `AssertJ` are you using?

There is a bug solved with Java 9 in `AssertJ Core 3.15.0`. I'd give it a go with `3.16` and see how it goes if you haven't tried it.

Comment: It's 3.16.1, the latest released one. You can grab the project here: https://github.com/unix-junkie/assertj-variance-issue